# Why does Ipywidget slider update variable only if it's an item from a list?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I created an ipywidget slider that, as you slide it, the image being displayed changes + the text displayed also changes. All images were previously stored in a list called image_data & same with the text, in a list called comp_scores. So, this works well (image/text change as slider is moved), but for some reason, when I call the "current_image" variable later- in another jupyter notebook cell-, it returns the original value ("1") which was set before I moved the slider, instead of the value that the slider was moved to.

However, when I set "current_image=[1]" (a list) and then interchange all "current_image" instances in the code below with "current_image[0]", and then I call current_image[0] later, it returns the updated value. Does anyone know why this is?

```
%matplotlib notebook
from ipywidgets import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

current_image=1
slider_fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4,2))
ax = slider_fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
line = ax.imshow(image_data[current_image], cmap='gray')

n = widgets.Text(
    value= "Comp Value: " + str(round(comp_scores[0][current_image],1)) ,
    description='',
    disabled=True)

display(n)

plt.axis('off')

def update(image=current_image):
    
    current_image=image
    
    line.set_data(image_data[current_image])
    slider_fig.canvas.draw()

    n.value="Comp Value: "+ str(round(comp_scores[0][current_image],1))
    
    
s_range=(0,24,1)
interact(update,image=s_range)
```

Comment: Scope would be my guess here. You'd want to access the widget setting a later cell and not just `current_image`. For the first situation you describe, `current_image` in the main scope is set to `1`. There's also `current_image` inside the `update` function that you change only inside that function. And presumably in the `interact` scope maybe as you pass it in(?). Just a guess based on what you describe because your posted code doesn't work, which makes it hard to test and also address what happens when you switch to a list. (Did you reset your kernel and run what you've posted?)

Comment: I was trying to point you to code where I have an example that gets `slider.value`, but Github is down right now. The easiest solution to your first issue (where you aren't getting the updated setting of `current_image` in another cell) is to add `global current_image` inside your `update` function. That's actually discouraged in general, but here it might be the easiest.

Comment: And disregard where I wrote, "You'd want to access the widget setting a later cell". I forgot the slider value isn't necessarily the image? (maybe it is, hard to tell because code you included broken.) I think one way to get the current_image  in the other cell without resorting to setting `current_image` as a global, would be accessing `line`'s current `data attribute is.

Comment: No, the slider value is just the image # (the label of the image basically).  I'll try the global current_image. Thanks!

Comment: Plus I should have added, if you wanted to access the stuff inside the widgets later (as in your other cell), you'd also want to assign it to something on that final line, like `a = interact(update,image=s_range)` so then you could check things like `a.widget.children`.